# Foreign Key Mapping friends of a User object

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, performance, software

I have been reading the Foreign Key Mapping section of the Martin Fowler's book(PEAA) and I really liked it but I can't see being a really good approach for problems like mapping friends to a user, since a user can have a lot of friends their approach of always loading all friends can take a lot of memory and time to copy the friends from the database. I thought of maybe having the User object contain a friends repository instead of making the user load it's friends by it self. What do you guys think?

Comment: What's a friend repository? Please elaborate.

Comment: By a repository I mean an object that for the domain it seams like a normal Set but it actually accesses the database and caches the retrieved items. An example can be found in this book:Implementing Domain-Driven Design

Comment: Keep in mind that not all of us have the books you're referencing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the operation is costly, **your proposed alternative is a good one.**

Such repository should have methods like `getFriend(int id)`, `exist(int friendID)` and it should be iterable. It should also have a `Friend getAllFriends();` method for a lazy loading of all Friends if the user of the API so requires.